# TextView gets smaller when containing two lines of text

Tags: android, textview

I have a simple horizontal LinearLayout with four TextViews with the same style inside. When the text in a TextView needs two lines, the TextView gets smaller:

[image]

I can't understand why. Anybody can help?

Thanks

**Layout**

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TextView style="@style/compte_ba_cell"
        android:background="@color/grey_header"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/montant" />

    <TextView style="@style/compte_ba_cell"
        android:background="@color/grey_header"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/origine" />

    <TextView style="@style/compte_ba_cell"
        android:background="@color/grey_header"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/echeance" />

    <TextView style="@style/compte_ba_cell_last"
        android:background="@color/grey_header"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/statut" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Style**

```
<style name="compte_ba_cell">
    <item name="android:layout_width">71.5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
 <style name="compte_ba_cell_last" parent="@style/compte_ba_cell">
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your third TextView to contain `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` this will fix your problem. I suppose the problem comes from something connected with "wrap_content" but I am not sure, if this is default value for layout_height. Also it does not make sense, why in the other cases, it will not wrap around the content and also be smaller.

```
   <TextView style="@style/compte_ba_cell"
        android:background="@color/grey_header"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/echeance" />
```

Comment: You're right. If I set `android:layout_height="50dp"` to my LinearLayout and `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to my TextView, it works. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this type of wierd things happens when the width or height provided for textview is not enough for your text.
Anywayz I'll suggest you to give height and width to your linear layout as per your requirement, and for your textview both height and width should be fill_parent.